# Add default text to iOS mail composer

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have:

```
[mailComposer setMessageBody:[self currentText] isHTML:NO];
```

Where emailComposer is just the iOS email composer view. I want to add to currentText another string. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self currentText], someOtherString];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
```

Comment: I'm getting an "expected : before someOtherString". It shouldnt be in quotes right? What could be the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting this warning. I don't see any problem with my code. How do you declare someOtherString?

Comment: Nm, this works:) How would I add a new line after currentText?

Comment: You need to have a look at NSString tutorials :P `@"%@\n%@"`